# ASP.NET core 3.1: does ConfigureAppConfiguration interacts with launchSettings.json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, kestrel-http-server

I'm experiencing a strange behavior when launching an ASP.NET core 3.1 web application from Visual Studio 2019 using kestrel (I mean the launching profile which does **not** use IIS express).

I have created a minimal application to reproduce the issue.

OS: **Windows 10 (build 19041.746)**
Visual Studio version: **Visual Studio 2019 version 16.8.4**

This is the csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>


</Project>
```

This is the launchSettings.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52222",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "TestWebApplication": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5002",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the Program.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace TestWebApplication
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
              webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
  }
}
```

This is the Startup.cs file:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace TestWebApplication
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
      Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddControllers();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
      if (env.IsDevelopment())
      {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
      }

      app.UseRouting();

      app.UseAuthorization();

      app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
      {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
      });
    }
  }
}
```

When I launch this web application by using the **TestWebApplication** profile from Visual Studio **everything works fine**: kestrel is launched at **http://localhost:5002** and the web browser is launched at **http://localhost:5002/weatherforecast**.

This is exactly what I would expect from the provided `launchSettings.json` file.

Consider the following change to the Program.cs, made to customize the application configuration sources:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace TestWebApplication
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
            {
              builder.Sources.Clear();
              builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
              webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
  }
}
```

This change breaks everything in terms of interaction with the **launchSettings.json** file. The following happens:

- kester is launched on both **http://localhost:5000** and **https://localhost:5001**
- web browser is **not** launched on **http://localhost:5002/weatherforecast**

Basically it seems that the file **launchSettings.json** is ignored and some defaults are used instead.

I have also observed the following:

- the root cause seems to be the line which clears the configuration sources: `builder.Sources.Clear();`
- the IIS express profile is **not** affected by this issue: it works as expected even with the modified Program.cs file

Is this a bug ? Am I missing anything ?

**SOME CLARIFICATIONS**

I'm clearing the configuration sources in order to have full control over the configuration sources themselves. Put another way, I would like to remove all the existing configuration sources and start from scratch. According to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#json-configuration-provider) this approach seems to be allowed.

Notice that the exact same code works as expected when using the `WebHost` class instead of the `Host` class. In that case the configuration sources can be fully customized and the ability to read the `launchSettings.json` file is maintained for Kestrel too. I'm trying to achieve the same effect with the generic `Host` class, which is the recommended class to be used instead of `WebHost` in ASP.NET core 3.1

Comment: When you clear your configuration sources you've removed whatever was telling Kestrel to bind to port 5002. This doesn't effect using IIS Express because your app itself isn't listening on port 5002, IIS is and is reverse-proxying the requests to whatever Kestrel is using internally.

Comment: @Valuator I'm doing so because I want to fully customize the configuration sources. The idea is removing all the existing sources and start from scratch. According to [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#json-configuration-provider) clearing the sources is supported.

Comment: @Valuator the same code works perfectly with ASP.NET core 2.2 and the `WebHost`. In that case clearing the configuration sources does **not** break the ability to read `launchSettings.json` and the `5002` port is maintained for kestrel too. Do you know how to achieve the same effect by using ASP.NET core 3.1 and the generic `Host` class ?

Comment: @Valuator when using `WebHost` instead of `Host`, **this exact same code works in ASP.NET core 3.1 too**. The problem seems to pop up only when using the generic `Host` class.

Comment: @Valuator just a little side note. Starting from ASP.NET core 3.0 the default hosting model under IIS is the so called in-process hosting model. See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/in-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-5.0#enable-in-process-hosting). So I guess that IIS express is not actually acting as a reverse proxy for kestrel.

Answer (score 6):

I have finally managed this issue.

That's not an ASP.NET core 3.1 bug, insted this is the way the generic `Host` is designed to work.

Basically the configuration for the port number which is specified inside the `lanchSettings.json` file is passed to the ASP.NET core application by means of some environment variables prefixed by `ASPNETCORE_`. These environment variables are set automatically by Visual Studio. The one responsible for the kestrel port binding is called `ASPNETCORE_URLS`.

When doing  `builder.Sources.Clear();` the configuration source for the environment variables prefixed by `ASPNETCORE_` is cleared away. So, in order to fix the issue, it is necessary to replace this configuration source:

```
.ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
            {
              builder.Sources.Clear();
              builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
              builder.AddEnvironmentVariables("ASPNETCORE_");
            })
```

All the details are available [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/30044)

Comment: This issue cost me a couple of hours, and your answer solved it.
Thx for sharing